# PHP save / store file to remote server?

Tags: php, networking, save, host

Is it possible for users to save / store their photos and videos to remote server, not localhost without using FTP but using web interface (php)?

If so, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a new form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
Choose a file to upload: <input name="file" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

In uploader.php you should have someting like:

```
$folder = "uploads/";

$path = $folder . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['file']['name']). " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

This is one of the simplest methods to upload a file to a server. However you might want to customize and add some more information to your file upload form.

Comment: This doesn't seem to address saving a file on a remote server.

Comment: Indeed, it's for saving on local server